# Check for unsaved change before moving to another window in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

let's say i have to xaml files. I can navigate from 1-st Window to the 2-nd Window. How can i warn the user before leaving the first Window with unsaved changes? I know i can use MessageBox.Show for the alert but i don't have any idea how to check the whole Window for changes.

Thanks in advance for your help
Georg

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement an IsDirty functionality. Best way to do that would be to write a Viewmodel for your Window.

Look at [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248045/isdirty-implementation-for-wpf) SO question to look how this should be done.