# Update WPF datagrid cell value when another cell is modifed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dataview

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a `DataView`. One of the fields is a last update time stamp. Is it possible to have this field update with the current date and time if 1 of 5 selected other fields on a given row is modified?

Thanks

Comment: You could use a DataTrigger

Answer (score 0):

When you do the actual save to the database is when you should update the update field using either     `DateTime.Now or DateTime.UTCNow`.

Look at this questions as well, [What is the best way to know if the user has changed data in the DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321899/what-is-the-best-way-to-know-if-the-user-has-changed-data-in-the-datagrid).

Comment: The datagrid is bound to a dataview. Upon update how would I determine that one of my 5 fields actually had a change?

Comment: There should be a `IsDirty` flag set. I've edited my answer to include a link to this exact same question.